# How to reverse a numpy array of unknown dimension?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, convolution

I'm just learning python, but have decided to do so by recoding and improving some old java based school AI project.

My project involved a mathematical operation that is basically a discrete convolution operation, but without one of the functions time reversed.

So, while in my original java project I just wrote all the code to do the operation myself, since I'm working in python, and it's got great math libraries like numpy and scipy, I figured I could just make use of an existing convolution function like `scipy.convolve`. However, this would require me to pre-reverse one of the two arrays so that when `scipy.convolve` runs, and reverses one of the arrays to perform the convolution, it's really un-reversing the array. (I also still don't know how I can be sure to pre-reverse the right one of the two arrays so that the two arrays are still slid past each other both forwards rather than both backwards, but I assume I should ask that as a separate question.)

Unlike my java code, which only handled one dimensional data, I wanted to extend this project to multidimensional data. And so, while I have learned that if I had a numpy array of known dimension, such as a three dimensional array a, I could fully reverse the array (or rather get back a view that is reversed, which is much faster), by

```
a = a(::-1, ::-1, ::-1)
```

However, this requires me to have a `::-1` for every dimension. How can I perform this same reversal within a method for an array of arbitrary dimension that has the same result as the above code?

Comment: `slice(None,None,-1)` is the same thing. Try indexing with a tuple of several.

Comment: @hpaulj Looking at the documentation, slice looks like it operates on single dimensional arrays. Does this work on multidimensional arrays because ultimately multidimensional arrays are stored as a single dimensional list and reversing the order of that list is equivalent of reversing every dimension of the multidimensional array? Also, does slice run in constant time like flip?

Comment: Look at `np.flip` code.  It constructs an `indexer` tuple that's a mix of `np.s_[:]` and `np.s_[::-1]` (depending on the dimensions parameter).  That's all I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.flip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html). From the documentation:

> `numpy.flip(m, axis=None)`
>
> Reverse the order of elements in an array along the given axis.
>
> The shape of the array is preserved, but the elements are reordered.

Note: `flip(m)` corresponds to `m[::-1,::-1,...,::-1]` with `::-1` at all positions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

```
slices = tuple([slice(-1, -n-1, -1) for n in a.shape])
result = a[slices]
```

extends to arbitrary number of axes. Verification:

```
a = np.arange(8).reshape(2, 4)
slices = tuple([slice(-1, -n-1, -1) for n in a.shape])
result = a[slices]
```

yields:

```
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])
>>> result
array([[7, 6, 5, 4],
       [3, 2, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: Try `slice(None,None,-1)`, or `np.s_[::-1]`